# Implementing top-k scala apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to implement top-k in scala within apache spark. I am aware that spark has a top action. But, top() uses reduce(). Instead, I would like to use treeReduce(). The main issue I have is that I cannot use these 2 lines of code which are used in the top() action within my Spark application.

```
val queue = new BoundedPriorityQueue[T](num)(ord.reverse)
queue ++= util.collection.Utils.takeOrdered(items, num)(ord)
```

These are made private. I know that I can use a `PriorityQueue` in Scala instead of a `BoundedPriorityQueue`. Is there an alternative for `takeOrdered` within Scala?

Comment: Why is takeOrdered/top using reduce() a deal breaker for you?

Comment: I'm working on a research project that compares the performance between the 2 approaches. So, I'd like to use treeReduce()

Answer (score 0):

Since (as per the comments), this is for a research project, you could add your own MyBoundedPriorityQueue which extends BoundedPriorirtyQueue and exposes the API in org.apache.spark in your own code. This isn't overly likely to work between versions of Spark, but if its just for research, that should do the trick. Best of luck and I hope you update us with your findings :)